# CloudFormation building a cluster and need pass Master IP to other resources

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template that I currently have hardcoded with IP addresses that I know I have in a subnet. Being part of a large corporation I need to make it dynamic as I create more clusters and have to reference IP addresses. In my current setup I have 1 master and a bunch of slaves that all need to know the master's IP. They do not need to know each other.

I have found the following:

```
"MasterNetInt" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface",
  "Properties" : {
    "SubnetId": { "Ref" : "MySubnet" }
  }
}
```

My question is that I just need to put this one resource and than under each of the 10 slaves have something like this:

```
    "UserData": {
                        "Fn::Base64": {
                            "Fn::Join": [
                                "", [
        "sed -i -e 's/server_host=localhost/server_host=", { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "MasterNetInt", "PrimaryPrivateIpAddress" ] }, "/g' /etc/master/config.ini \n",
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the ref name is "MasterNetInt" this should work to give you the IP

```
 "Fn::GetAtt": [
                            "MasterNetInt",
                            "PrivateIp"
                        ]
```

Comment: Template error: resource MasterNetInt does not support attribute type PrivateIp in Fn::GetAtt But this works: PrimaryPrivateIpAddress